# Otimizar querie que retorna o conjunto de registros de múltiplas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho costume de utilizar a seguinte estrutura de querie para retornar a quantidade de registros de tabelas do meu banco mysql:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(tab1_codigo) FROM tabela1 where alguma coisa) AS total1,
  (SELECT COUNT(tab2_codigo) FROM tabela2 where alguma coisa) AS total2,
  (SELECT COUNT(tab3_codigo) FROM tabela3 where alguma coisa) AS total3      
FROM tabela4;
```

"alguma coisa" se refere a algum filtro específico que realizo dentro de cada querie.

A querie funciona perfeitamente! No entanto, com o objetivo de tornar essa querie mais otimizada, tentei delimitar a quantidade de registros, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(tab1_codigo) FROM tabela1 where alguma coisa limit 50) AS total1,
  (SELECT COUNT(tab2_codigo) FROM tabela2 where alguma coisa limit 50) AS total2,
  (SELECT COUNT(tab3_codigo) FROM tabela3 where alguma coisa limit 50) AS total3      
FROM tabela4 limit 1;
```

Ao rodar a querie, percebi que é retornado um erro por causa das cláusula "limit 50". Somente a cláusula "limit 1" (inserida no final) foi aceita sem apresentar erros. Alguém poderia me explicar um pouco sobre o funcionamento deste tipo de estrutura de querie? É possível eu utilizar a cláusula limit dentro dessas queries ou algum meio mais adequado de eu trabalhar com esse tipo de estrutura?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa um `COUNT()` ele percorre todos os registros dento da sua consulta.

Então você primeiro tem que usar o `LIMIT` na pesquisa com `WHERE` e depois usar o `COUNT()`, desta forma você terá a contagem de registros quando for menor do que o limite estipulado senão trará o limite.

Você pode fazer a consulta usando o **`LIMIT`** dentro de *`subqueryes`* como no **EXEMPLO** abaixo:

### SQL:

```
SELECT * from 
  ( select count(*) as total_cores from 
    (
      select cor from `cores` where cor like 'Ág%' limit 20
    ) as A1
  ) as A2
join 
  (select count(*) as total_nomes from 
    (
      select nome from `nomes` where nome like 'A%' limit 20
    ) as B1
  ) as B2;
```

Criei um exemplo de tabelas e como usar o código acima no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f501372/20)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f501372/20